# How do I get a JSON field with the name part#

Tags: javascript, json

The title really sums it up, when I try to access the field, I get a parse error in javascript

```
var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).features
for (var x in data) {
   var o = data[x];
   Ti.API.info("part number" + o.part#);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/) to access properties with names that include characters not allowed in an identifier.

```
o['part#']
```